# Flutter : how to left aligned a checkbox

Tags: flutter

I am adding a check box and list title to my app. However, these item are not left align with the other widgets. How can I align it with the other widgets

here is a picture

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your code so we can see whats going on?

Comment: @dcg I created a pastebin https://pastebin.com/f0RDZdar

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can use `CheckboxListTile` widget which has property called `controlAffinity`. Setting it to `leading` will make the checkbox left aligned. Below is sample working code:

```
CheckboxListTile(
  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
  title: Text('I agree to the Terms and Conditions'),
  value: monVal,
  onChanged: (bool value) {
    setState(() {
      monVal = value;
    });
  },
)
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: Yes `controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading` move the checkbox to the left side, but how to reduce the padding? so that checkbox can be in line with the labelText above?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal Use `dense: true`, and `visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact` to reduce the padding.

Comment: @Ryan Hmm its not working.. Yes It gave the text beside the checkbox a move, but what i mean is how to move the whole checkbox padding to the left along with the text..

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal I guess that is the parent widget do the trick.  Try reducing the padding in the parent widget.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late but `CheckboxListTile` class has a `contentPadding` property which is set to horizontal 16 padding by default.
Adding this line made the trick for me:

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0)
```